# Issue in creating refreshed stream

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, ksqldb

I have a use case that can be described as follows:

- Dump that is generated each day at 4 am
- Online stream that is run from 12 is for 24 hours.

We use dump as lookup, any content that exists in the online stream and also in the dump will have a special offer, but we face a problem as our proposed solution is limited. We created a stream that joins between lookup dump stream and online stream for 24 but we face a problem as there is a gap because the dump is not ready before 4 am so the join find nothing in those 4 hours and if we changed the window period for more time we will lose each day refreshment data.

Any help?

Comment: It would be useful if you showed your KSQL commands and data

Answer (score 0):

This question was cross-posted on the ksqlDB GitHub page: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/7935

Copying my reply from there:

> This is tricky... You need to understand that a joins have temporal semantics. For a stream-table join, it implies that a stream record joins to the table "version" that is valid according to the event-time of the stream record. Thus, if you table updates are timestamps at 4am, all stream-records from 12am-4am happen *before* the table update and are not eligible "see" those updates.
>
> And even if you can change the timestamp of the table updates to 12am, the issue is that ksqlDB does not support a GRACE PRIOD for stream-table joins yet (we are already working on this though)...
>
> Bottom line might be, that you would need to work around the current ksqlDB limitations to change your upstream ingestion  to "wait" until after all table updates got published, before you publish the stream updates... Not sure if this is possible in your end-to-end setup.
>
> To learn more about temporal join semantics, check out this Kafka Summit talk: https://www.confluent.io/events/kafka-summit-europe-2021/temporal-joins-in-kafka-streams-and-ksqldb/